# XCTest.framework red xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, target

After updating to XCODE 7.0.1 my XCTest.framework red

[image]

[image]

I have deleted paths in test targets and even added new test target. Still getting same problem.

Help please.

Comment: CMD+Shift+Alt+K try to clean like this

Comment: Done it loads of times. Still problem